# Executing powershell scripts in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, c#-4.0

Below is the script I am using to try and execute my powershell script but whenever i run it i just get a blank command window.

#### C# Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Backup Reporter\Required\edit_website.ps1");

    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
        // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(text);

        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
        foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
        {
            // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
            // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential NRE.
            if (outputItem != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }
        if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

#### Powershell Script

```
 $text = "test test test"
```

All I want to do is output test to the command window.

Comment: Formatting improved (edit confirmation pending). You forgot to add a blank line between text and code.

Comment: Do you get the expected output when you run your PS script directly? If not, you should focus on execution policy.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Execution policy is definitely set correctly, the PS script itself is literally just declaring a variable and that's it

Answer (score 1):

You can use Write-Output instead of Write-Host. It works for me while invoking from winform application.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be correct, however your script does not give any output. So that is why you do not see the output of the script. Add:

```
Write-Host $text
```

This will give you output that is printed at the line:

```
Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not give any output.You could use the command write-output on your script, to have an output.[As [kpundir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8416035/kpundir) refer]

```
Write-Output $text
```